# ZonedDateTime.format() returns a String. Can this string be converted to a Date(or any related Date classes)

Tags: hibernate, date, java-8, java-time

I have a date `String` 'date' coming in as an input. I am converting this string to `LocalDate`, to which I set a timezone (say partner's timezone). This gives me the time in `ZonedDateTime`. So far so good!

Now I have a `Date` field in the database, to which I have to compare this date of mine. So I format this `ZonedDateTime` value to the format of the date in the database. I use the `format()` for the same, which returns a `String` value of the formatted date in the desired format.

**The problem starts here.** I want this `String` value (refer to `zonedDateTimeUTC`  in the code), to be compared to `Date` column in the Database using Hibernate. If I use the `String` value directly, I get an exception saying incompatible types. I tried searching for options to set this `zonedDateTimeUTC` to any equivalent date object (`ZonedDateTime` is the most appropriate I suppose). But I couldn't do it. Could you guys guide me through this.

```
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
if(null != date && !date.isEmpty()){

    //Get ZonedDateTime in Partner's time zone
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);
    LocalDate localdate = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
    ZonedDateTime zoneDateTime = localdate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of(timeZone));

    //Getting the date in UTC format
    String utcPattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS";
    String zonedDateTimeUTC = zoneDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("+00:00")).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(utcPattern));
 }
```

The Hibernate Code uses the criteria API. The code in chunks in as follows:

```
Session session = getSessionFromSessionFactory(getSessionFactory());
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<ImportRequest> criteriaQuery = 
criteriaBuilder.createQuery(ImportRequest.class);
Root<ImportRequest> importRequestRoot = criteriaQuery.from(ImportRequest.class);
criteriaQuery.select(importRequestRoot);
List<Predicate> restrictions = new ArrayList<>();
if (transferReqSearchVO.getReceivedOnStartZonedDateTime() != null){
     restrictions.add(criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(                                           
                    importRequestRoot.get("received"),
                    transferReqSearchVO.getReceivedOnStartZonedDateTime()));

}
if (null != restrictions && !restrictions.isEmpty())
    criteriaQuery.where(restrictions.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
TypedQuery<ImportRequest> importRequestQuery = session.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
return importRequestQuery.getResultList();
```

The received date field in the domain is specified as follows:

```
@Column(name = "RECEIVED_ON", updatable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date received; 

public Date getReceived() {
    return received;
}

public void setReceived(Date received) {
    this.received = received;
}
```

Comment: can we see hibernate code you have tried

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia i added the chunks of code :)

Comment: If the database field's type is a date, then pass a `Date` to it. You can convert the  `ZonedDateTime` to `Date` with `Date.from(zoneDateTime.toInstant())`. Date objects [have no format](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date)

Comment: @Hugo worked!! Thanks :)